# Why are vectors not required to preserve their norms by multiplication (|a * b| = |a| |b|)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

While Quaternions are required to preserve the norm by multiplication. Hamilton when trying to extend complex numbers used triplets at first but due to violation of this condition extended to quadruplets. Whereas vectors which came later specifically violate that condition and have been accepted. What loss/benefit does that extra condition have?
(Is there is any type of vector multiplication which preserves the norm?)

Comment: What happens when ${\bf a} \neq {\bf 0}$ and $b \neq {\bf 0}$ but ${\bf a} \cdot {\bf b} = 0$, i.e., the vectors are perpendicular?

Answer (score 2):

Note that when talking about multiplication of vectors, we have to say *which* multiplication we are talking about.

Note that Hamilton's goal with quaternions was to get something as close as possible to a field; what he managed was a division algebra, which differs from a field only by the fact that multiplication is not commutative.

Now, what multiplications do we have with vectors?

First, there's the multiplication of a vector with a scalar, resulting in a vector. For *this* multiplication, we indeed have $\left|\alpha\vec v\right| = \left|\alpha\right|\,\left|\vec v\right|$. Note however, that this is not a product in the sense of a division algebra, since the two factors are not from the same set.

Next, there's the scalar product (aka dot product). Here we in general have $\lvert\vec a\cdot\vec b\rvert\ne \rvert\vec a\vphantom{\vec b}\rvert\,\lvert\vec b\rvert$. However, again this would not be a candidate anyway because the result of the product is a scalar, not a vector.

Then there's the vector product (aka cross product). Here finally at least both operands and the result are all vectors. However, again in general we don't have $\lvert\vec a\times\lvert\vec b\rvert \ne \lvert\vec a\rvert\,\lvert\vec b\rvert$. And given that $\lvert\vec a\times\vec b\rvert$ is the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, that would not be possible anyway.

---

But then, the question remains: Could we define *another* reasonable product $\vec a*\vec b$ that fulfils the condition $\lvert\vec a*\vec b\rvert = \lvert\vec a\rvert\,\lvert\vec b\rvert$?

Well, first, what is a “reasonable” product? Well, the first thing it has to be is a product, that is, it should adhere to the distributive laws:
$$(\vec a+\vec b)*\vec c = \vec a*\vec c+\vec b*\vec c$$
and
$$\vec a*(\vec b+\vec c)=\vec a*\vec b+\vec a*\vec c.$$
Note that this alread implies that for rational numbers $q$, we have
$$(q\vec a)*\vec b =q(\vec a*\vec b) = \vec a*(q\vec b).$$

Next, we want it to be continuous. Which generalizes the above equation from rational to real $q$. This in turn means we only have to fix the product for unit vectors, that is, vectors with $\lvert\vec a\rvert=1$. Note that the condition then the norm condition implies $\lvert\vec a*\vec b\rvert = \lvert\vec a\rvert\,\lvert\vec b\rvert = 1$

Finally, the Euclidean space is isotropic, that is, no direction is inherently different from another. We expect a reasonable product to respect that isotropy, that is, if you rotate the two factors the same way, the product should rotate with them. More formally, if $R$ is a rotation, then we want $R(\vec a)*R(\vec b)=R(\vec a*\vec b)$. Note that all the products above fulfil that condition.

So what do those conditions imply for our new product?

Consider first, $\vec e_1*\vec e_1$. We need this to be an unit vector, and any rotation that keeps $\vec e_1$ fixed also has to keep the result fixed. This gives only two possible solutions, differing only by sign: Either $\vec e_1*\vec e_1=\vec e_1$ or $\vec e_1*\vec e_1=-\vec e_1$.

Let's call that sign $s$, that is, $\vec e_1*\vec e_1 = s\vec e_1$, with $s=\pm1$. Now from the conditions above, one easily derives that for an arbitrary vector $\vec a$, we have
$$\vec a*\vec a = s\lvert\vec a\rvert\vec a.$$

Now let's specifically apply this to $\vec a=\vec e_1+\vec e_2$. Then we get
$$(\vec e_1+\vec e_2)*(\vec e_1+\vec e_2)=\sqrt{2}s(\vec e_1+\vec e_2).$$

On the other hand, we get from the ditributive law
$$\begin{align}(\vec e_1+\vec e_2)*(\vec e_1+\vec e_2)
&= \vec e_1*\vec e_1+\vec e_1*\vec e_2 + \vec e_2*\vec e_1 + \vec e_2*\vec e_2\\
&= s(\vec e_1+\vec e_2) + \vec e_1*\vec e_2 + \vec e_2*\vec e_1.\end{align}$$

Thus we get
$$\vec e_1*\vec e_2 + \vec e_2*\vec e_1 = (\sqrt2-1)s(\vec e_1+\vec e_2)\ne 0 \tag{1}$$

But then, by a $90$ degree rotation, we can rotate $\vec e_1$ to $\vec e_2$ and $\vec e_2$ to $-\vec e_1$, therefore we get by rotation invariance
$$\vec e_1 + \vec e_2 = \vec e_2*(-\vec e_1) = -\vec e_2*\vec e_1$$
and therefore
$$\vec e_1*\vec e_2+\vec e_2*\vec e_1 = 0. \tag{2}$$

Now clearly conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ contradict each other. Therefore there cannot be such a product.

---

So how did Hamilton solve this issue? Well, he added a “direction” that is *explicitly different*, namely the scalar “direction”. That is, unlike with the identification of $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$, the scalars are no longer the same as one of the vector directions, but are a “direction” on their own. Since this direction is *explicitly distinct* from the vector directions, the above considerations don't apply to it. And indeed, it turns out that this way it works.

---

OK, but why do we use vector spaces, and not quaternions, these days? Well, vector spaces are much more flexible than quaternions (to begin with, they work in arbitrary dimensions). And since vectors and operations are two different concepts anyway, it isn't too bad to have them in different algebraic structures. And with vectors not required to at the same time represent rotations, there is no need to preserve norms in multiplications of vectors.

But if you want a norm-preserving product, there are also other ways to extend vector spaces, known as geometric algebra. Geometric algebra works on any dimension, and also incorporates concepts like the exterior product, a generalization of the cross product. Indeed, the geometric algebra for three dimensions includes the quaternions as subalgebra.

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions are not required to preserve its norm! Its the other way around:
Quaternions are really useful to compute rotations, which are defined to be norm preserving operators.

Thus, in most cases where you do computations with quaternions, the norm preserving attribute of the oprator is present.

However: Dont confuse the norm preserving multiplication $||Ax||=||x||$ with $|(x,y)|\neq|x||y|$.

Of course, there are orthogonal quaternions, where the direct product is $0$, which would directly violate your question.

Comment: Hamilton wanted his “numbers” to represent both vectors and rotations, with the application being represented through multiplication. Which implies that norm preservation must hold for quaternions.